# PM2 - Need to restart after deploy

Tags: javascript, node.js, jenkins, continuous-integration, pm2

I have a node API made using PM2 for proccess manager and Jenkins for CI, my problem is, after the jekins run the code is on server and i do the  `pm2 reload`, but for the changes go live i need to do manually a `pm2 restart` on server. Anyone faced this? I tried every topic on stack overflow and forum

Comment: Simply enable watch mode? `pm2 start myapp.js --watch` will restart the app whenever a file changes

Comment: I tried, but the changes only reflect with manually restart